# After migration from M1->M2 Url rewrite issue

Tags: magento2, migration

After migration M1->M2, in url_rewrite table more records found.

**In m1-> `core_url_rewrite` table exists row:1000000**

**In m2(after migration)->`url_rewrite` table exists row:12000000**

And some path exist in both `request_path` as well as in `target_path`

Like:

**in m1-> `request path`(favourites) **

**in m2-> 2 rows found with**

`request path`(favourites) `target_path`(wishlist)

`request path`(wishlist) `target_path`(favourites)

Comment: m2 database is fresh or not ?

Comment: @RonakRathod yes when i have started migration

Comment: with sample data or without sample data ??

Comment: @RonakRathod without sample data